# Loading Retina Display Image from Flickr (Using Three20 TTThumbnailViewController)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, three20, flickr

I'm currently using three20's thumbnail view to load images from flickr, the only problem is that they're coming back pixelated. Does anyone know what I could do to fit in an image scale so it looks decent?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your image URL, Flickr offers different image size with `suffixes`, you can find them in Flickr API documentation: https://secure.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

Comment: Thank you, I immediately fixed it. However now I've ran into another problem. Since the images displayed are now bigger, the scrolling performance sucks. In my other views with images I use SDWebImage, but how exactly would I use it here. Should I use it in my photo.h or photosource? Thank you so much!